# While updating database using command 'update-Database' error coming "Login failed for user ''

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Unable to update database using command 'update-Database' Error:

> Login failed for user ''.

I am using code first based approach to create database. Here is my connection string

```
    appsettings.json:
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "devconnection": "Server =DOTNET; Database = PaymentDetailsDb, Trusted_connection=true"
  }

 public class PaymentDetailContext : DbContext
    {

        public PaymentDetailContext(DbContextOptions<PaymentDetailContext> options):base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<PaymentDetail> paymentDetails {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Add-Migration is working as expected but update-Database is throwing error 'Login failed for user ''.'

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/555332/login-failed-for-user-error-message-when-you-log-on-to-sql-server might be a useful resource for you. There are 3 scenarios which might be the reason for the problem. Unfortunately you haven't told us anything about the setup of your SQL server, so you'll have to work out which scenario applies to you based on your own knowledge of the server

Comment: @ADyson In SQL server i am able to connect using  Servername: DOTNET, Authentication: Windows Authentication. But  using connection string : "Server=DOTNET;Database=PaymentDetailsDb,MultipleActiveResultSets=true, Integrated Security=SSPI;" i am unable to connect

Comment: Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB working fine for me but do not know why i am not able to connect using Server= DOTNET

Comment: Neither do I, because I don't know anything about your server. You'll have to figure it out based on the setup of that server. This is all about context. I cannot read your screen, your disk, your server...or your mind. That's why I gave you that link - you can read about the scenarios and work out which one applies to your situation. e.g. if your DOTNET server doesn't support login using Windows authentication, or doesn't recognise your Windows username, then you'll have to use a SQL Server username/password instead. That's one possible reason, but I can't prove it either way

Comment: P.S. "unable to connect" is not a useful description of the problem. Instead tell us exactly what error you get. If it's the same error as in the question, fine, but still please confirm that for us. If you changed the connection string it's entirely possible you got a different error...but we don't know unless you tell us. Again, we're not mind-readers.

Comment: Can you post more details about the project your using? .net core? How does your dbcontext know about your connection string

Comment: @ChenChi Yes i am using .net core. in startup.cs  services.AddDbContext<PaymentDetailContext>(options=>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("devconnection")));